# ARM equivalent for x86 asm constraint "x" (256-bit vector operand)

Tags: c++, arm, simd, inline-assembly, neon

I want to execute the assembler instruction `vrhadd` in C++ using `__asm__`.
I need to map the following function to ARM-specific instructions (using `vrhadd`), since the given codebase was developed on x86-64 and im using ARM64.

`__asm__("vpavgb %[a], %[b], %[c]" : [c] "=x" (res) : [a] "x" (a), [b] "x" (b));`

Where a, b and c are 256-bit SIMD register. Executing this line on my system throws:

`error: couldn't allocate output register for constraint 'x'` , because (I guess) `x`, as the constraint of the input operands, stands for a 256-bit vector operand in an AVX register (x86). On ARM it represents a 32, 64, or 128-bit floating-point/SIMD register in the ranges s0-s15, d0-d7, or q0-q3, respectively.

Since I could not find one, I was wondering if there is a direct equivalent of the x86-constraint `x` for ARM64?

Comment: On x86, an `x` constraint is either XMM (128-bit), YMM (256-bit), or ZMM (512-bit), depending on the type of the variable you use with it.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html.  Or from [In GNU C inline asm, what are the size-override modifiers for xmm/ymm/zmm for a single operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34459803) - clang used to(?) only accept `"x"` for vectors 128-bit vectors?  Not sure when `"Yt"` and so on are needed.  Anyway, I don't expect any of that to be the same for ARM.

Comment: Maybe [GCC What's the right inline assembly constraint to operate with ARM VFP instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12610375) .  And I think [gcc arm inline assembler %e0 and %f0 operand modifiers for 16-byte NEON operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51476786) is showing a working example.

Comment: Erm... you do realize that the NEON vector unit is only 128 bits wide?  So it makes sense that there wouldn't be any constraint for a 256-bit vector - there is no register that could hold it, and no way for the machine to process it.  You're going to have to split up your 256-bit vectors into two 128-bit chunks and operate on them separately.  (Or is your question about the proper constraint for a 128-bit vector as the closest "equivalent"?)

Comment: On the other hand, why use inline asm here at all?  ARM/ARM64 SIMD has perfectly good [intrinsics](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vrhaddq_u8); that would avoid the whole issue as well as enabling better optimization.  [Obligatory link to DontUseInlineAsm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)

Comment: @NateEldredge Uhhhhh.... Sorry, I don't agree. I could show you many examples proving the opposite. Especially compilers for `aarch32` generate FUBAR machine codes when doing permutations (`vtrn`, `vzip`, and `vuzp`). But you are right on the other hand: inline assembly is only good for short inline functions.